# Response headers missing with http status code 102

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http-status-codes, response-headers

I'm currently developing a `REST API` in which I need to return a `102 HTTP status code` (processing) while I'm generating an export.

Workflow :

1. POST /exports

   - return 201 with data
2. GET /exports/id

   - return 102 with data if the export is processing
   - return 200 with data if the export is completed

When I try to retrieve export data while it's processing, there are no response headers: response headers are missing with 102 HTTP status code. If I change the status code with 2xx for instance, it's working fine. I can't figure out. Is there anything specific with the 102 HTTP status code? When I say response headers are missing I mean: `Chrome > Developer tools > Network Tab > Click on request > Headers tab > Only showing "General" and "Request Headers" (same with FF & Postman)`.

Used Technologies :

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- PHP 7.2 (latest release)
- laravel/lumen 5.6.21
- Apache 2.4.29

Controller Code :

```
 /**
 * Return export by id
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 *
 * @throws AuthorizationException
 * @throws ModelNotFoundException
 */
public function getItem(int $id)
{
    if($export = Export::find($id))
    {
        $this->authorize(__FUNCTION__, $export);

        if($export->status != Export::STATUS_COMPLETED)
        {
            return response()->json($export, 102);
        }

        return response()->json($export);
    }

    throw new ModelNotFoundException();
}
```

Expected Request Headers :

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Cache-Control
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Content-Type
- Date
- Proxy-Connection
- Server
- Vary

### EDIT

I should have mentioned that it worked on my previous config :

- Ubuntu 17.10 LTS
- PHP 7.1 (latest release)
- laravel/lumen 5.6.16
- Apache 2.4.27

I haven't found in any release notes what could have impacted the request answer.

Comment: I don't think that is how 102 should be used. It should only be used as interim response, meaning that the full response will come after x period of time. In your case I think you would need to send a different json and have the consuming application re-try after x period of time.

Comment: @Tuim It's how it's implemented : create an export and then check every seconds if it's done. Easiest solution is to return 200 no matter what and check the export status in the response's body. But I was looking for the real reason / particularities of the 102 http status code.

Comment: I think this question/answer might help you along: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316208/http-status-code-for-still-processing

Comment: Try making the request via different client Postman, curl etc.. and see if it shows response header - in postman use log for this.

Comment: You are asking about the HTTP headers when there is not a single reference to the header() function in the code you've shown us?

Comment: @symcbean I don't have to manually set response headers ; laravel/lumen framework automatically set them for me. For all others requests, I get the expected headers I listed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HTTP 202 Accepted` instead.

See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316208/http-status-code-for-still-processing

**Explained:**

RFC 2518 says "The server MUST send a final response after the request has been completed", and this is interpreted to mean that your server needs to send an  final response code *in addition* to the initial `HTTP 102`. Not doing so creates timeout problems for clients waiting for a final response but not getting one. Firefox will choke, Chrome will time out and convert it into `HTTP 200 OK`. cURL will inform that there is unread content.

So use `HTTP 102 Processing` only as a hint to clients that, "Okay, but this might take a minute...", after which you follow up with a final code and response body.

If it is a long running process that you want to periodically poll, use `HTTP 202 Accepted` and close the response.

It's also worth noting that `http_response_code()` does not handle `HTTP 102`.

**Bad Example:**

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 102 Processing'); exit; ?>
```

**Good Example:**

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 102 Processing'); // let client know it might take a while
sleep(2); // do stuff that takes a while
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); // counterintuitive, but works
```